# How do the speed reductions from Spirit Guardians and Ray of Frost interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, stacking

The *Spirit Guardians* spell changes a creature's speed while they're in the area:

> An affected creature's speed is halved in the area

The *Ray of Frost* spell temporarily changes a creature's speed on a hit:

> On a hit, it takes 1d8 cold damage, and its speed is reduced by 10 feet until the start of your next turn.

If my human cleric is concentrating on *Spirit Guardians* while adjacent to a **gladiator** (speed 30 ft.), and my ally the sorcerer hits the gladiator with a *Ray of Frost*, how many feet can the gladiator move (without dashing) on his next turn?

- Does the half-speed effect from *Spirit Guardians* apply before the 10-foot reduction from *Ray of Frost*, thus making the gladiator's speed `(30 ÷ 2) - 10 = 5`?
- Does the 10-foot reduction from *Ray of Frost* apply before the half-speed effect from *Spirit Guardians*, thus making the gladiator's speed `(30 - 10) ÷ 2 = 10`?
- Do they interact in some other way?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before. The linked question even includes the exact example calculations you provide here.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thanks for the link. I tried searching and failed to find that.